# LocalStorage Backbone.js

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js, backbone-local-storage

Can anybody tell me

is it possible to get and set values in localStorage

Here is my code

```
 var TodoApp = {}; 

    TodoApp.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        title : '',
        done : false
      }
    });

   TodoApp.list = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      model: TodoApp.model,
      localStorage:  new Store("local")
    });

    var todoList = new TodoApp.list()
```

can i use todoList.localStorage.setItem() for this

Comment: Yes, in fact there are several plugins available that make it easier to do so for example https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage and https://github.com/nilbus/Backbone.dualStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localStorage is a key value persistence in the browser. All values must be strings. So you would stringify your JavaScript objects:

localStorage.setItem("myKey", JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"}));

Comment: Thank you Chris ..    But here i want to store all data in the new localStorage object "local"  my question is- can i do that manually by using some set or get stuff?

Comment: Yes you can, it has nothing to do with backbone. Just use the native functions